# Sorting a dictionary in Python by keys to values

Tags: python

I need to sort a dictionary based on the keys, and then return the values associated with those keys.

```
ages = {40 : 'mother', 38 : 'father', 17 : 'me'}
['me', 'father', 'mother']  # Should return this
```

What is the fastest possible way of doing this (performance is really an issue for me, as the sorting gets called thousands of times throughout my code).

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not valid Python syntax, and you have one key that is a string. Is that a mistake?

Comment: If sorting is called thousands of times in your code, you might want to cache some of the results or use an ordered dictionary instead.

Comment: please use `:` to separate key:value.

Comment: Oh i'm very sorry , i don't know what i was thinking. Yes, it was a mistake. Edited the code accordingly. Thank you :d.

Answer (score 4):

Since your keys are numeric and by default iterators over dictionaries return the keys - you can sort the keys directly:

```
>>> ages = {40:'mother', 38:'father', 17:'me'}
>>> [ages[k] for k in sorted(ages)]
['me', 'father', 'mother']
```

Comment: While technically it doesn't sort the dictionary, it gives the output wanted by OP.

Comment: dictionaries are not "sortable" by default.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: Well the OP asked for a specific output. Since this answer provides it, I think it's correct.

Comment: I know. You also don't sort the keys as you say, but return a list of them sorted.

Comment: The question didn't ask how to sort keys, it asked how to return the values as a list based on keys that are sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Making use of the [`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) and [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) functions:

```
zip(*sorted(ages.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))[1]
```

First it sorts the dictionary creating a list of tuples (the items):

```
>>> sorted(ages.items())
[(17, 'me'), (38, 'father'), (40, 'mother')]
```

Then it takes only the values:

```
>>> zip(*sorted(ages.items())[1]
('me', 'father', 'mother')
```

P.S. If the dictionary is very big you may want to consider using [`dict.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.iteritems#dict.iteritems) which on Python 2 returns an iterator. On Python 3 this is the default behaviour and it is provided by [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.items#dict.items).

---

Alternative solution - using [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.itemgetter(*sorted(ages))(ages)
('me', 'father', 'mother')
```

Comment: `key=lambda item: item[0]` is the default, you can safely omit it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort a dictionary due to the nature of this kind of collections. Although Python gives you several options: either use `OrderedDict` (to keep the order of inserted key/value pairs), or just sort the keys, e.g.::

```
ages = {40 : 'mother', 38 : 'father', 17 : 'me'}
ages_sorted = sorted(ages) 
# or ages.iterkeys() / .keys() (in Py3) which is a bit self-explanatory.
```

Comment: You don't need to add `.keys()`, by default dictionaries are iterated over their keys.

Comment: On the other hand .keys() / .iterkeys() is an explicit call which gives a quick idea of the variable type on the left side.